# algebra factorisation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can I simplify $$\frac{(a+2b)(a-2b)-4ab}{4b(a+2b)}$$ to $$\frac{a-2b-4ab}{4b}$$ by cancel out the same factor. Any help is thanked.

Comment: Just cancel out the $(a+2b)$ factor and you will get your equation

Comment: This is algebra (precalculus), not linear algebra. Linear algebra is matrices, determinants and so on which you will study during STPM and beyond.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

Let $a=2, b=1$, the first expression becomes $\frac{0-4(2)(1)}{4(1)(2+2)}=-\frac12$ while the second expression becomes $\frac{2-2-4(2)(1)}{4}=-2$.

They are not equal. The second term of the first expression doesn't have a factor of $a+2b$. It's likely a typo.